# Can I do a short internship in the Netherlands with my French titre de séjour?

Tags: student-visa, schengen, non-residents, internship

I was doing my Master's in France and currently hold a titre de séjour (student visa or residence permit) with which I can travel around the Schengen area. As part of my Master's thesis, I got a 6-month internship offer in Arnhem, Netherlands. Is it possible to stay in the Netherlands with this visa card and, if I have to register in the municipality, what are the procedures?

Comment: AFAIK you would be able to visit other Schengen states for 90 days, but not more than that. If you are living in NL for 6 months, and presumably making money there, I would guess you need a visa. But I'm really not sure. This may be a duplicate of https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/7192/have-valid-study-visa-from-a-schengen-country-do-i-need-work-visa-for-swiss-for?rq=1 -- You should speak to your course coordinator in France to find out about this.